# Creating a Wait List in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's Say, I have a Header Table with two Columns (Name and Date).

```
Paul | 10/12/2002  
Donna | 07/11/2000  
Gary | 03/14/2021
```

And I want to create a waitlist/que driven by oldest date first

```
Select * Order By Date
```

I can easily create a Next-Up style of que by sorting ASC or DESC on Date.

But I need to go a step further.  I need to have my SELECT include a temporary column that shows what number, in the que, a person is.

So - Gary logs in and sees that he is 3'rd in line, but only sees his information.

Expected Results:

```
Name:  Gary     Date:  03/14/2021   Position:  3
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results please. See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. (And a date has a year field, a month field, etc.)

Comment: Column date data type?

Comment: Date is a date typ column.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `row_number()` function like:

```sql
Select Name, Date, row_number() over(order by Date ASC)
from table
```

Comment: I did a quick test on this, and it gave me the same row_count number for each record in the query.  It listed every record sorted correctly, but every count was = 1.  They were all = 1.  I need to know their actual place in the que

Comment: @ExecChef: you need to remove `partition by name`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Worked perfectly.  Exactly what I was looking to do.  I appreciate your (and others) help.